# How to add legend in Basemap with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to put a legend in my world map. Every point is a different kind of devices from a different tweet. 
[image: World map]

Here is my code:

```
import geocoder
import json
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def openJSON(file, path):
    with open(path + file + '.json', 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
        return data


def App_users(data):
    android_users = []
    iphone_users = []
    other_users = []

    #3 types of users: Android, Iphone and others:
    for a, b, c, d in data:
        if "Twitter for Android" in d:
            android_users.append([a, b])
        elif "Twitter for iPhone" in d:
            iphone_users.append([a, b])
        else:
            other_users.append([a, b])

    data = (android_users, iphone_users, other_users)
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    posXY_add = []

    for d in data[0:50]:
        if d["user"]["location"] != None:
            g = geocoder.google(d["user"]["location"])
            if g.latlng != None:
                a = g.latlng + [g.address] + [str(d["source"])]
                posXY_add.append(a)

    data = App_users(posXY_add)

    map = Basemap(llcrnrlat=-70, urcrnrlat=70,
                    llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, epsg=3395)
    map.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D', xpixels = 1500, verbose= True)

    colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
    increment = 0

    for app in data:
        for item in app:
            if len(item) == 2:
                lat, lon = item[0], item[1]
                x, y = map(lon, lat)
                map.plot(x, y, colors[increment] + 'o')
        increment += 1


    plt.title("Geo-position Twitter Devices")
    plt.show()
```

Have You any suggests to improve my map? Different colors, different map or else?
I am using Python 2.7 by Pycharm. My sample data is:

```
([[21.8974003, 83.39496319999999], [40.2671941, -86.1349019], [10.4805937, -66.90360629999999]], [[50.719164, -1.880769], [37.0903748, -94.5134078], [44.9862701, -93.39398279999999], [47.6062095, -122.3320708], [-27.4697707, 153.0251235], [20.593684, 78.96288]], [[43.2648545, -79.9492978], [39.1767262, -94.4867155], [33.7489954, -84.3879824], [39.7392358, -104.990251], [38.8761634, -77.0337777], [41.0082376, 28.9783589], [36.0753128, -95.95646269999999], [36.0595387, -95.90582429999999], [29.7604267, -95.3698028], [21.3014947, 106.6291304], [21.3014947, 106.6291304], [-16.6868982, -49.2648114], [10.4805937, -66.90360629999999], [45.037149, -92.825929], [33.760818, -78.967556], [45.49340369999999, -73.82329179999999], [39.750545, 37.0150217]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Legend part:** it's the same way you would put a legend into a plot - simply call `plt.legend()` with `m.plot()` having the `label` argument. So, in your case it would be:

```
handle_dict = {
    "Andriod" : 0,
    "iPhone" : 0,
    "Other" : 0
}
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
increment = 0

for app in data:
    for item in app:
        if len(item) == 2:
            lat, lon = item[0], item[1]
            x, y = map(lon, lat)
            map.plot(x, y, colors[increment] + 'o', label = 
                handle_dict[type_phone] if handle_dict[type_phone] == 0
                else "_no-legend_")
            handle_dict[type_phone] += 1
    increment += 1

plt.legend()
plt.title("Geo-position Twitter Devices")
plt.show()
```

You'd also have to modify your code to identify the type of phone that is being plotted (hence the variable `type_phone`).

Here's the link to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) regarding legends to modify the legend.

**Making the map better:**
Personally, I like to use `map.shadedrelief()` for these world views - it's not as dark as `map.bluemarble()` and you can easily see the points better. There's really no need for the `map.arcgisimage()` argument here because you have a world view rather than a zoomed in view - it'll generate your map a bit quicker if you use the built in function. I'd also add the `markeredgewidth` argument to `map.plot()` to make the marker edge width to be something other than zero because right now your points look like they're blending in with the background. It'll make your dots pop out more.

Oh - also take time out to upgrade to Python 3 if you're able to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate. Unfortunately the problem has not been fixed because I am visualizing the label in the legend a lot of times. So I have on my legend a lot of red points with "Android". I am not able to show only the three labels.

Comment: Ah - oversight on my end. I went ahead and edited the post to include `label = handle_dict[type_phone] if handle_dict[type_phone] == 0 else "_no-legend_"` in `map.plot()` and added in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the issue with a trick. An iteration on my code on "a"; in this way I just plot the first label of the category. In code:

```
handles = [("Android",None), ("iPhone",None), ("Other devices",None)]
colors = ['r', 'g','b']
increment = 0
for app in data:
    a = 0
    for item in app:
        if len(item) == 2:
            lat, lon = item[0], item[1]
            x, y = map(lon, lat)
            map.plot(x, y, colors[increment] + 'o', alpha=0.8, markersize=0.1, label=handles[increment][a])
            a = 1
    increment += 1
plt.legend(loc='lower left', shadow=True)
```